# pandas set one cell value equals to another

Tags: python, pandas, select

I want to set a cell of pandas dataframe equal to another. For example:

```
station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==573,'longitude']=station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==5152,'longitude']
```

However, when I checked

```
station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==573,'longitude']
```

It returns `NaN`

Beside directly set the `station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==573,'longitude']`to a number, what else choice do I have? And why can't I use this method?

Comment: What does `station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==5152,'longitude']` itself return?

Comment: A  float number which I can manually assign to station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==573,'longitude']. However, if I need to scale up, I cannot do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html), or use `.values`:

```
station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==573,'longitude']=station_dim.loc[station_dim.nlc==5152,'longitude'].values[0]
```

For the assignment to work - `.loc[]` will return a `pd.Series`, the `index` of that `pd.Series` would need to align with your `df`, which it probably doesn't. So either extract the value directly using `.get_value()` - where you need to get the index position first - or use `.values`, which returns a `np.array`, and take the first value of that array.

Comment: It would be useful to explain that the assignment is done based on the index, which (most likely) explain the `NaN` value.